# NSImage gets tiled when drawn to a NSRect with width greater than 2000px

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage

I am trying to overlay an image over an NSOpenGLView.  All works well unless the view gets stretched beyond a width of 2000px.  Here is how I apply it to the NSOpenGLView.  Bare in mind I am essentially plugging into another application, so this function is kind of a hack.

```
- (void)applyOverlay {
    NSWindow* mainWindow = [[NSApplication sharedApplication]mainWindow];
    NSArray* subViews = [[mainWindow contentView] subviews];
    NSOpenGLView* openGLView = subViews[0];
    Overlay* overlay = [[VRayOverlay alloc] initWithFrame:[openGLView frame]];
    [openGLView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
    [openGLView addSubview:overlay];
}
```

My overlay class looks like this

```
@implementation Overlay

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)rect
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:rect];
    if (self) {
        self->image = [[NSImage alloc] initByReferencingFile:@"/my_path/scribbles.png"];
        [self setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    [self->image drawInRect:dirtyRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:0.5];
}

@end
```

This is what the result looks like when the width is under 2000px
[image: Over 2000]
And this is what the result looks like when the width is over 2000px.  Also, notice the last tiles to the right are stretched to fit into the view frame.
[image: under 2000]

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?  I have tried different images of various sizes and the effect seems to be the same.